# Notepad++ won't work with Python

Tags: python, notepad++

I'm just getting into programming and took the common advice of using a free text editor with python. I seem to be running into a problem and everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.

I downloaded [Anaconda from this url](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and whenever I put the location of python.exe into the run bar: C:\Users\Home\Anaconda2\python.exe all I get is the python console to pop up. I've tried adding: "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" to the end as one user had suggested, but that just opens up the console and closes it immediately after. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you trying to run a script you wrote in Notepad++? Are you familiar with the command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I meant that notepad++ won't run any python scripts. I think I'm familiar with cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I usually create a space for all my projects. Usually `C:\projects` so it's easy to find. Then I create a folder for specific work. I'd do `C:\projects\learningPython`.

Now, create a new file and save it to `C:\projects\learningPython\hello-world.py`

In the file put this line

```
print('Hello World!')
```

Then click save.

Now open a command prompt (enter `cmd` in the run bar)

now enter this in the command prompt:

```
python C:\projects\learningPython\hello-world.py
```

Hopefully this will work for you. Let me know if you do not see 'Hello World' appear on the command prompt.

Comment: That did work, but as soon as I tried to run a simple Pyplot script it just sent me back an empty line. I'm primarily interested in scientific applications, so if it can't plot points this won't work. Also it's rather inconvenient to go to cmd all the time. 

Edit: it actually did plot the points just fine, but that still leaves the problem that this is a rather roundabout way of getting it to work.

Comment: @Astrum you might try getting started with [IPython](http://ipython.org/)    the installation instructions are [here](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html). It's a great interactive way to get going with python.

Comment: @Astrum It is not a roundabout way, nearly everybody is doing it that way. You are basically typing "python myscript.py", which is simple enough. Get familiar with the command-line if you want to develop. IPython is also command-line, just nicer.

Answer (score 2):

After you followed nlloyd instructions and you are assured that your setup works and you can use Python from the commandline, I would use the nppexec Plugin to integrate Python (and other external tools) with notepad++ . (You can get it from [Notepad++ PluginCentral](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Central) or directly via the Plugins -> PluginManager.)
There I would create a nppexec script: with the following lines (use Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute... ):

```
npp_save
C:\Tools\Python\Python.exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

- change `C:\Tools\Python\Python.exe` to whereever you have installed python
- save this nppexec script
- use the commands `Execute...` and `Direct execute previous` from Plugins -> Nppexec menu to select the nppexec script (if you have several) and repeatedly use the same nppexec script